# Where are the supply spots on the multiplayer maps?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Each multiplayer map has some point where you can get supplies (stock up your ammo / grenades).

One always seems to be near the drop off location, but the other are spread around the map.

Where are those points exactly?

Comment: i dont like this question...

Comment: @Paralytic care to specify why?

Comment: could you specify which map you want seems like if you play multiplayer at all youd have a good idea where the ammo dumps are. There are only 3 per map so its not hard to find idk maybe im just being pissy.

Comment: @Paralytic there are 6 maps and I'm not sure I know every location, and I thought it would be quite a handy resource (even if the question is a bit broad)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a rough sketch of Reactor, the red circles are the ammo boxes. 
[image]

Dagger:

[image]

White:

[image]

Giant:

[image]

Glacier(Missing 1??  This map might only have three.):

[image]

Ghost:

[image]

Condor(The upper right one may be a little off; need to double check it):

[image]

Hydra:

*Need to play this map a few more times to get a sense of its shape.*

Not pretty, I know, but hopefully gets the point across. I miss any locations, let me know in the comments and I'll add them in.

Comment: +1 any for an awsome job in my opinion, wish i could edit the pics somehow.

Comment: You are actually missing 3 on firebase white

Comment: +1 - awesome job. For reference: In white, the two missing points are at the bottom of the "inside" stairs, and on the bottom-left side of this map (the biggest open rectangle in the map), near the L-shaped short-cover.

Comment: And in Giant: one is at the bottom left area of the map, near the initial spawn point, and (I think) the other is at the top left of the map.

Comment: great job, exactly was I was wishing for :D

Comment: On Glacier, there is one in the bottom room, near the middle of the rightmost wall on your map. On Ghost, there is one by the entrance to the first building on your left from the second courtyard (the one furthest from the spawn point), as well as another one in the building on the far end of that courtyard.

Comment: @hammar I added the one on glacier, but can't quite visualize the ones for Ghost.  I'll try a game on that map tonight and try to scout them out.

Comment: The bottom-left one you added from my comments in White should be at the bottom-center of that rectangular area instead of the bottom -left.

Comment: And the bottom-left one in Giant you added from my comments is close, but actually in the bottom-right corner of the area, not the bottom-middle.

Comment: There are five points listed on White now -- I don't remember the one at the bottom right. Isn't there only the one directly "north" of the landing circle, not "east"?

Comment: @ChrisPhilips Yep, there are 5 on White.  I double checked.  I think the second one near the launch pad is so that there is a place to resupply during extraction where you won't get swarmed.